# Leiningen tries to call java.exe from a wrong/missing JDK

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

Some time ago, there were two versions of JDK installed on my PC (1.7.0_09 and 1.7.0_51). Then I uninstalled the former one. Now, when I try to run `lein run` (even with a dummy project) I get the following message:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin\java.exe" (in directory "<...>"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

What can I do to make `lein` use the right JDK? The `JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME` variables are not set.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Leiningen?

Comment: Do you find any references to Java when you get the 'path' variable at the command line: 
c:> echo %path%

Comment: @ChrisDevo none.
>where java => C:\Windows\System32\java.exe, >java -version =>
java version "1.7.0_51"

Comment: What about
c:> javac -version

Comment: @NielsK, that was :java-cmd in the user profile, thank you very much! :)

Comment: @NielsK transform your comment into answer so I can upvote :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check the following settings:

- Does `java -version` show the right version ?
- Does a system variable `JAVA_HOME`,`JDK_HOME`,`JAVA_CMD` or `LEIN_JAVA_CMD` point to the wrong JDK ?
- Does your leiningen project profile have a `:java-cmd` setting forcing a specific JVM ?
- Does your leiningen user profile `~/.lein/profiles.clj` have a `:java-cmd` setting ?
- When using an IDE with built-in leiningen, is your IDE project JDK the right one ?
- Were changes made to lein.sh / lein.bat ?

Comment: I just had this error and it was a case of point 4, profiles.clj.

Comment: it is 'java -version' not '--version', but I can't edit just one character.